# Unable to connect machines on a local network

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, ip, static-ip

I have 3 systems -

1. Windows 10 system with firewall disabled
2. CentOs 8 system with firewall disabled (firewall status is inactive)
3. Windows 10 VM on the CentOs 8 machine described above with firewall disabled

For some reason, I am unable to connect these 3 on a single network. All 3 machines have been given static IPs, as -

**Static IP -**

```
192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.125, 192.168.1.25
```

**Subnet mask -**

```
255.255.255.0
```

**Default gateway -**

```
192.168.1.1
```

The Linux system and Windows 10 `VM` hosted on top of it connect fine (via a host adapter for `VirtualBox`, having adapter `IPv4` value as 192.168.1.11), and can even ssh into it.

However, the `Windows 10` standalone system is unable to locate,`ping`or even `ssh` into any of these systems. With `dynamic IP` provided by my provider, they are able to connect well enough, but when I connect the 2 systems (Windows 10 and Linux systems) via an ethernet cable in a standalone, sort of p2p network, they just do not find each other.

`IPv6` is disabled in each of the network configurations. The only thing I can think of is that the machines do not specify the same `workgroup`, since my Windows 10 system is signed on to a domain, and my Linux system (with Windows 10 VM) is not, but in the scenario described above, there is no domain activity, since the machines are connected via LAN cable and are not on any other network.

UPDATE -

**ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:04:5f:9e:94:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::204:5fff:fe9e:9443/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:04:5f:9e:94:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:31:3c:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:31:3c:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-c91ce55ad4d6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e6:4e:bd:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-c91ce55ad4d6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ca:60:cc:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.11/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ip route**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 100 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-c91ce55ad4d6 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.11 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.10 metric 100 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Comment: What subnet numbering do your physical systems use?

Comment: All have the same subnet numbering - 255.255.255.0

Comment: I wasn't asking about the subnet mask, it says nothing without the network number itself. What actual IP addresses do the physical machines use?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Windows 10 physical machine has 192.168.1.25, Linux physical machine has 192.168.1.10 (VM has 125 at the end).

Comment: Has the Linux system been configured with some kind of bridge between the LAN and the VM interface?

Comment: The Linux system, not itself. But on virtualbox, which is what is running the VM, a host adapter has been configured with IP 192.168.1.11. Using this, the physical Linux system and vm are able to connect. On the VM, I configured the static IP in the usual way, by changing the adapter settings to use a static IP and disabling IPv6. Workgroup, is different  from the windows physical system, though, which is signed on to a domain, and where I cannot change it to a workgroup

Comment: Could you include (edit in) the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` on the Linux host? VirtualBox "host adapters" are _not_ internal to VirtualBox – they're actual network adapters on the host OS.

Comment: Updated the question with the output. I had initially put in a bridged network on the vm, which allowed the vm to be accessible to the Win10 physical system, but the host and vm couldn't talk. I then connected the vm to the host-only adapter which allowed at the host and the vm to connect to each other, but the vm became inaccessible to the Win10 physical machine . My final desire is to have both static and dynamic IPs on the host, with the vm connected on to the static IP network, and be accessible to any machine on that static ip network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Linux system and Windows 10 VM hosted on top of it connect fine (via a host adapter for VirtualBox, having adapter IPv4 value as 192.168.1.11), and can even ssh into it.

Your problem is here. You have **two physically separate networks** which just happen to be numbered `192.168.1.x` on both sides. However, they're still separate networks; packets do not automagically flow from one interface on the host Linux system to another.

Your VMs might still have Internet access because you or your VM software has probably configured the Linux host to act as a router/gateway, complete with NAT. (NAT is duct tape for networks.)

However, because the network numbers are the same on both sides, your VMs think that every 192.168.1.x address is *local* (that's what the subnet mask tells them!), so they do not use a gateway to reach them. As a result the two sides cannot reach each other in normal configuration.

The Linux host also doesn't cope well with two interfaces being on the same subnet. You can see that `ip route` has two entries for the same destination; only one of them is used. The OS doesn't keep track of which individual hosts are on which side.

You have four options:

- Continue using routing, but change the VirtualBox "Host adapter" (vboxnet0) IP address to a different network, e.g. 192.168.2.x will do the job.
- Merge both networks using Linux bridging: Create a *bridge* on the host (ip link add br0 type bridge), then put both your real Ethernet and the VirtualBox virtual interface into the bridge (ip link set eth0 master br0). Remove IP addresses from both interfaces, and configure 192.168.1.11/24 on br0 (the bridge) instead.
- Merge both networks using VirtualBox bridging: Change the VM configuration to use "Bridged networking" and select the physical Ethernet interface. This will only work as long as your Ethernet is configured.
- Create two interfaces in the VM: one for host networking like now, one for bridged networking with your physical Ethernet.

> The only thing I can think of is that the machines do not specify the same workgroup,

Absolutely irrelevant. The *only* thing a "workgroup" does is limit which machines show up in the List Of Network Computers, practically. (The NetBIOS "computer browsing" mechanism was designed in 1980s and workgroups were used to limit how much data each LAN computer had to hold.) It does not affect communication at IP or TCP level, and for that matter it doesn't even affect direct Windows SMB file sharing connections.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried option 3, but I may have missed something...On Linux host, my ethernet is configured with the static IP (192.168.1.10). I changed the adapter setting to `bridged` in my VM network adapter setting, removed the host only adapter and selected the host ethernet which is configured with the static IP. I restarted my VM, and checked it still had the static IP (192.168.1.125) which I had configured earlier. I suppose after all this, my VM and my host are on the same physical network. But the host and VM are still unable to ping or find each other.

Comment: My Win 10 physical system, when connected  at the other end of the ethernet cable, is indeed able to connect to the VM, essentially the same scenario as I had described in my last comment to the original question. The problem is that the host and VM are unable to discover each other.

Comment: That's definitely not usual for VBox's "bridged networking" (I just tested again to be sure). On the Linux host, can you at least `arping` the VM? (Regular communications might be blocked in the VM's firewall configuration, but ARP is the bare minimum that always works as long as you're both in the same subnet.)

Comment: And if IPv4 doesn't seem to work, have you tried using IPv6 instead? Even without actual IPv6 Internet access, you always have the `fe80::*` "link-local" addresses which can be used for same-subnet testing.

Comment: `arping` does not work either. Says `suitable device could not be determined`. There is no` firewall` active on any machine (Win 10, Linus and VM Win 10). `IPv6` is disabled on all configurations. Baffling that I am able to reach the VM from physical Win 10, but not the actual host. Bridging allows the VM to see the network directly, and not use the host's network stack, but why would the VM and host be opaque to each other..and the physical win 10 and host.I'd think bridging blocks the adapter for usage by host, if it weren't for the fact that even without, physical machines can't talk.

Comment: Ah, some distros' arping version requires the interface to be specified: `arping -I enp1s0 192.168.1.25`. Both kinds of bridging leave the adapter usable by the host. (VirtualBox's bridging uses a driver to magically intercept the packets; Linux's bridging creates a new interface that explicitly links the bridged ports.) In this situation, I'd be curious whether packets can't pass in _both_ directions, or just in one...

Comment: Though in your post, the Ethernet interface actually reports "link down" at this time, so maybe that's part of the problem? Did you test when it was also connected?

Comment: I checked it when the link was up. I shall check with `arping` and re-verify that nothing is missed out in the entire procedure. With the network configurations being used from scratch, and an understanding of the answer given above, there should not be a logical reason why this is not working.

Comment: Turns out, it was a third-party service routine which was blocking traffic. Works fine as described. Thanks a lot.